# Not able to add a different tint color to right bar button for navigation bar in iOS 7

Tags: ios7

My current application runs on iOS 5 and 6. The navigation bar is having orange color and the right bar button is having gray color. Also the right bar button is having a bordered style. However the same application when I run on iOS 7, I observe the right bar button is transparent style and is having the same orange color as the navigation bar. Please tell me if there is any way to make the navigation bar and bar button items look almost the same as it was previously in the case of iOS 5 and 6. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


UIButton *listbtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[listbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[listbtn setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor] withBorderWidth:0];
[listbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[listbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(leftDrawerButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:listbtn]];
```